# Inscribing equilateral triangle in square -- mistake in historical work by Abu'l-Wafa Al-Buzjani?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, math-history

In David Wells's "Curious and Interesting Puzzles", Penguin, 1992, his Puzzle 38 is taken from a work (unspecified) by Abu'l-Wafa Al-Buzjani (but I suspect it could be "A Book on Those Geometric Constructions Which Are Necessary for a Craftsman"), reproduced, apparently, in J.L. Berggren: "Episodes in the Mathematics of Medieval Islam", Springer, 1986.

"Construct an equilateral triangle inside a square, so that one vertex is at a corner of the square and the other two vertices are on the opposite sides."

This is one of the three constructions provided in the solutions:

[image]

Let $M$ be the midpoint of $CD$.

Construct $MB$.

Construct an arc centre $B$ and radius $AB$ to cut $MB$ at $N$.

Produce $DN$ to $H$.

$DH$ is then one side of the equilateral triangle, where $DG = DH$ is one of the other sides.

Except it's not. $GH$ is longer than $DH$.

Analysing the angles, it turns out that $\angle CDH = \arctan \frac {3 - \sqrt 5} 4$, which is about $10.8$ degrees.

So clearly this is a mistake. (Wonderful though Wells's books are, they are often riddled with errors, from simple typos and misattributions through to bad mathematics.)

I have been unable to find online copy of either Abu'l-Wafa Al-Buzjani's work or J.L. Berggren's (and at this stage I am unable to hunt it down in a library, and unwilling to get a copy of my own), so I have not been able to find out whether the mistake is Wells's (mistranscribing the construction), or whether it has been sitting there all this time in Abu'l-Wafa Al-Buzjani and nobody has noticed it, or halfway between the two.

Is anyone able to throw any light on what is shown in those source works -- and if the error is in there as well, has anyone else ever noticed this?

Or even: am *I* the one to analyse this all wrong?

Comment: If you're after accurate sourcing, then the [History of Science and Mathematics StackExchange](https://hsm.stackexchange.com) may be a good place for this question.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.

Comment: Yup, [WA](https://tio.run/##VY7BCoMwEETvfoVHTRNNejSmn1AKPYoH04gpdCuYUBTJt9tN6KWX2VkezAwM3o4w@OdjOA7TqJ1TEeSEZqU8SItG0C3IzPFG3efXZ@z2wrCprJIqVUzM4hOV/gOTQFS6XjhdWwzCu7UiUEzfQi8ziPn1OXYa7PLEnArBfEms1KkaNwA6RyACVxIts9vyfPvuOi/QgWa6z@sq/00zVinQmO@oDwk43h/HFw) gives $|BN|=\sqrt{\frac{5}{3}}\cdot(-1 + \sqrt{3})$

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin I don't understand what that means. $BN$ equals $AB$ which is whatever the length of the side is.

Comment: Note now also cross-posted on the HSM SE site at [Inscribing equilateral triangle in square — mistake in historical work by Abu'l-Wafa Al-Buzjani?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/12068/10368).

Comment: @JohnOmielan Yes, that is what I was advised to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your analysis is correct.  Here is a corrected figure below.  Rather than joining $B$ and $M$, the correct point of intersection is simply that of the circular arc $AC$ with the perpendicular bisector of $DC$.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for this. The question arises: what then was the point of constructing $BM$ in the first place? Is this the original construction in Abul-Wafa's work?

Comment: In discussion of this question at the Maths History stackexchange, it has turned out that this construction (creating the line $BM$) never appeared in Abul Wafa in the first place. So it seems to have been a fabrication by Wells.